# Laravel 5.4 ShouldQueue Not sending email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an event listener, which will fire a notification when the event is triggered. 
Notification email is sent when I don't implement ShoulQueue class. When ShouldQueue is implemented,email is not sent. I have added my code below.

**Listener:**

```
class CustomRequestListener
{
  public function handle(CustomRequestCreated $event)
  {
     $user->notify(new CustomRequestEmail());
  }
}
```

**Notification Class**

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CustomRequestEmail extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Test Mail')
            ->view('layout.testmail.template');
    }
}
```

**queue.php**

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),

'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],
    ....
   ]
```

**.env**

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Comment: What's the queue driver you are using on .env?

Comment: QUEUE_DRIVER=sync on .env

Comment: Is that your actual listener? If yes, you are missing a `)` here: `$user->notify(new CustomRequestEmail());` and in any case `$user` should not be available in that scope.

Comment: @Mozammil, No, that is not my actual listener, I have removed some code in order to make is small and clear on the question. This perfectly works if I remove implements ShouldQueue from my CustomRequestEmail class.

Comment: Sorry I missed the queue driver bit. How about your mail driver?

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp , the whole code works if I remove the  implements ShouldQueue from my CustomRequestEmail class. Email notification is also sent. Just that when I implement ShouldQueue, it does not work. Should I run any artisan command or use any other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing this on a **local environment**?

If this is the case you should listen on the queue otherwise nothing will be triggered

Following commands will start your queue. Leave the command running to keep listening:

- If using horizon: `php artisan horizon`
- Not using horizon: `php artisan queue:work`

**Not local?**

Make sure you have a queue worker running on your server, this needs to be reset when you deploy new code. Using horizon with supervisor a nice way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try again in the following way (I assume that you did instructions in Laravel docs but someday it's not working):

Step 1: drop table 'jobs' in your database.

Step 2: run command 'php artisan migrate' in console to create table 'jobs' again.

Step 3: run command 'php artisan queue:work' in console

Step 4: retry your app

Note that in .env file, you set up:

QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

QUEUE_DRIVER=database

P/s: It works for me!

Hope it works well for you.